# Qemu Booting from floppy hang, Bootloader

Tags: operating-system, kernel, qemu, bootloader

I have very simple bootloader which i am trying to run through qemu in linux.

But qemu gets idle and show "booting from floppy"

I dont know how to make it work!
I have included bootloader code and makefile script.

Here is the code for the bootloader

```
org 0
bits 16
jmp boot1

bootmsg db "Preparing to Load Operating System", 0x0a,0x0d,0x0
print:
or al,al
jz .printdone
lodsb
mov ah,0x0e
int 0x10
jmp print


.printdone:
ret



boot1:
cli
mov ax,0x07c0

mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov ax,0x0000
mov ss,ax
mov sp,0x07c0
sti

mov si,bootmsg
call print
hlt



times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

and here is my Makefile script

```
boot.bin: boot.asm
    nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin

boot.img: boot.bin
    dd if=/dev/null of=boot.img count=1 bs=512
    dd if=boot.bin of=boot.img conv=notrunc

qemu: boot.img
    qemu -fda boot.img
clean: 
    rm *.bin *.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lodsb before check al

```
bootmsg db "Preparing to Load Operating System", 0x0a,0x0d,0x0
print:
lodsb
or al,al
jz .printdone

mov ah,0x0e
int 0x10
jmp print


.printdone:
 ret
```